# PHP :Scan qr code on mobile and open a link

Tags: php, laravel, qr-code

I am trying to achieve the following:
When I scan an QRcode on mobile it should open the website/Link.

I have setup the code below and when I scan the QR code it shows a popup to  open the link: http://index.html. However I want the page to open automatically without user interaction.

```php
  $image = \QrCode::format('png')
    ->size(300)->errorCorrection('H')
    ->generate('http://index.html');
    $output_file = 'QR.png';
    Storage::disk('local')->put($output_file, $image);
```

The popup after scanning the QRCode - [iOS scan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZzoA.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if the `index.html` file is intentional but loading a local file isn't possible. Automatically opening a page without user interaction isn't possible either on iOS with the default camera app. You could implement a custom scanner in your own app.

Comment: @katariya_ganesh Could you mark this answer as solutions so others can find it?